# Comparing a list of integers with a number prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to define a predicate which takes as input a list of integers, and instantiates X with the elements of L smaller than 10, and Y with the elements of the list greater than or equal to 10.

This is the predicate: `separate(L, X, Y)`

Here are some examples of the output I'm looking for:

```
?− separate([2, 13, 4, 0, 55], X, Y).
    X = [2, 4, 0]
    Y = [13, 55]

?− separate([2, 3], X, Y).
    X = [2, 3]
    Y = [ ]
```

Comment: Of interest: [partition/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=partition/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple. Here a solution without built-in predicates:

```
separate([],[],[]).
separate([H|T],LG,LL):-
    ( H > 10 -> 
        LG = [H|TG],
        separate(T,TG,LL) ;
        LL = [H|TL],
        separate(T,LG,TL)
    ).

?- separate([2, 13, 4, 0, 55], X, Y).
X = [13, 55],
Y = [2, 4, 0]

?- separate([2, 3], X, Y).
X = [],
Y = [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break it up into multiple clauses:

```
separate( []     , []     , []     ) .
separate( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ,    Zs  ) :- X <  10, separate(Xs,Ys,Zs).
separate( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  , [X|Zs] ) :- X >= 10, separate(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

Easier to read. Better expresses intent, too, as well as not making assumptions about the content of the list — e.g., what happens with `[1,12,3,x,9,28]`?